# How do I send a json payload along with an image to a FastAPI instance?

Tags: python, api, fastapi

I am using FastAPI to receive an image, in the following way:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/file')
def _file_upload(my_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    image_bytes = my_file.file.read()
    decoded = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(image_bytes, np.uint8), -1)
    return {"file_size": my_file.filename}
```

Now, if I want to send json payload along with the image, how do I do it?

Example:

```
import requests
filename = "test_image.jpeg"
files = {'my_file': (filename, open(filename, 'rb')), 'some_other_data': 'hello'}
response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/file', files=files)
print(response.json())
```

In the above example, how do I access the `some_other_data` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a Request Body, the endpoint will parse it anyway.

You are sending a request which looks like this

```py
files = {
    'my_file': (filename, open(filename, 'rb')), 
    'some_other_data': 'hello'
}
```

The endpoint expects two parameters `my_file` and `some_other_data`, since the `some_other_data` is a `str`, you can send it like this

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Body

@app.post('/file')
def my_endpoint(my_file: UploadFile = File(...), some_other_data: str = Body(...)):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. However, when I send the request, I keep getting `{'detail': [{'loc': ['body', 'some_other_data'], 'msg': 'str type expected', 'type': 'type_error.str'}]}`.  Am I sending the request wrong, or am I handling it wrong on the server-side?

Comment: Probably you are doing something wrong on the client side.

Comment: How did you send the request ?